# Why shouldn't PostGIS be installed in the PostgreSQL database "postgres"?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis

The PostGIS [installation documentation](http://postgis.net/install/#column_right) reads:

> PostGIS is an optional extension that must be enabled in each database you want to use it in before you can use it. Installing the software is just the first step. DO NOT INSTALL it in the database called postgres.

We're running PostgreSQL in Docker and only need one database, so we've been using the default database, `postgres`. My first inclination was to install PostGIS there, but the documentation seems pretty clear that we shouldn't be doing that.

Is there a reason for PostGIS not to be installed on the default database, or is this note meant to deter people from accidentally installing PostGIS in the `postgres` database when their data is in the `foobar` database?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your data in the postgres database too? If so, won't that make upgrading hard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no danger in installing PostGIS into the `postgres` database.  The note is just so users don't confuse themselves, as you suspected.

Comment: Perhaps, but if so the note should be updated to provide accurate information. Ex: `please install postgis in a dedicated schema in order to prevent data corruption`.   Or: `we recommend installing postigs in a dedicated "postgis" schema, though installation would technically succeed in any dedicated schema`.  
By the way, I guess that installing postgis in the public schema, and data in another schema is also bad practice, because users could create tables in public schema by mistake.